# Web services eliminating weak ciphers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ssl, tls1.2

We have an application that calls out to a Government web services to pulls data into our system. They have eliminating “weak ciphers” and now only support three. I am getting some errors that the system can't create a `secure channel`. Is there something else I need to do for this to work?

Error

```
An exception has been thrown: (System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

Code

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol =
                SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 |
                SecurityProtocolType.Tls |
                SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Service Code

```
private T Run<T>(string url, string queryString) where T : new()
        {
            T result = default(T);

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(queryString).Result)
                {
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        result = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>().Result;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new Exception($"Resourse {url}{queryString} failed: {(int)response.StatusCode} ({response.ReasonPhrase})");
                    }
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Currently supported ciphers:

```
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
```

Comment: This is a client software or server version and/or configuration issue.  It should probably be posted on https://serverfault.com/

Comment: The client software is using the SecurityProtocol  setting and the server is only supporting the ciphers.

Comment: If your system is running properly up-to-date software versions and is properly configured, why this question?  And it's still not a code problem and should be on ServerFault.

Comment: @AndrewHenle [sf] cannot help with debugging your code.

Comment: @MichaelHampton **What** code?  If this is a code problem, it doesn't provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @AndrewHenle Indeed. This post needs a lot more information.

Comment: I can add the Service Code  but I am not sure how that will help it just creates a HttpClient

Comment: Why are you skipping TLS 1.1 in setting of the `SecurityProtocol` property?

Comment: What is your .NET runtime and which version? Together with your OS, does it support TLS 1.2? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls#support-for-tls-12. I think SHA256+ is supported only by TLS 1.2+.

Comment: The Application is using .Net Framework is 4.5 and the web server is Windows Server 2012 R2